# CSS transform scale (down) doesn't center element using margin 0 auto when scaled element was bigger than container before scaling

Tags: html, css

It appears that when scaling down an element which previously did not fit in its container, `margin: 0 auto` will no longer center the element within its parent (note that using `transform-origin: center center` does not solve this). This is because the auto margins seem to apply before the scaling rather than after (I expected the latter).

While playing with this, I eventually managed to center the element within its container, but only using absolute positioning:

```
position: absolute;
transform: translateX(-50%) scale(0.5, 0.5);
left: 50%;
```

This is a very popular technique, but in this particular case, it is important to place the translateX function **before** the scale function, as these are executed in the defined order.

Following is a snippet of code to illustrate the issue (also on CodePen: https://codepen.io/liranh85/pen/qVewQp)

```css
.container {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.scaled {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 600px;
/*   width: 400px; */
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
/*   transform: translateX(-50%) scale(0.5, 0.5); */
  margin: 0 auto;
/*   position: absolute;
  left: 50%; */
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scaled"></div>
</div>
```

Notice that:

- The element is not centered using auto margins when its width is bigger than its container's.
- When giving the scaled element a width smaller than its container, it will remain centered after scaling (e.g. try using `width: 400px`).
- When using absolute positioning, as mentioned above, it is possible to center the element.

I'm wondering:

- Has anyone else run into this issue?
- Is this the best way to center such an element?
- Am I correct to say the auto margin cannot be used to center such an element?

Comment: I'm a bit lost on what you're asking. Just some notes. Scale should not be part of your positioning(maybe scale a child if you want to) Margin auto only works on remaining space, not negative.
For centring you could do something with `calc` and `vw` or `flex`(see related questions)

Answer (score 8):

You need to use

```
transform-origin: center;
```

Take a look at some of the docs on this
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Answer (score 5):

Your suspicions are correct: when the element is too wide to fit within its parent, `margin: 0 auto` will not horizontally center the element. It will instead cause the element to overflow at the far right edge of its parent.

You can center your element properly by using `translateX(-50%)` before you scale the element, on top of positioning the element absolutely and using `left: 50%`. The reason why this works is because by absolutely positioning your child element, you are taking it out of the layout flow of the parent and therefore can position it in the horizontal center of the parent.

**Note:** This solution assumes that you are using `height: 100%`. If vertical centering of a non-full-height element is required, update the styles so that you're using `translate(-50%, -50%` and `top: 50%; left: 50%`.

Here is a proof-of-concept example based on your code you've provided:

```css
.container {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.scaled {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) scale(0.5, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scaled"></div>
</div>
```