# Center absolute positioned div with translateX and overflow: auto without margins

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying a very easy way to center and preserve the full size of a div without success, look at this snippet:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  
  float: left;
  
  margin-right: 20px;

  position: relative;
}

.body.smaller {
  width: 200px;
}

.container {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  position: absolute;
  
  overflow: auto;
  
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.child {
  width: 300px;
  height: 1000px;
  
  position: absolute;
  
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="body smaller">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As can be noticed in this snippet, the first sample is correctly rendered and centered but the smaller one is not, the green left border is cropped someway.

How I can show the entire content of the div using the `translateX` transform option and without tricks like `margin: 0 auto;` or similar statements?

I would achieve this in combination of a scaled container div with the possibility to scroll the child div, I tried all possible combinations without luck.

**Update:** please not that all sizes are not prefixed, these are just sample width and height, so no forced calculation should be done to achieve the expected result.

**Update 2:** I cannot use the `margin: 0 auto;` way to center the div because I'm trying to achieve a particular result. Look at this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Emulator000/79c5L6o8/12/

```js
function scale() {
    let children = document.getElementsByClassName('child');
  for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    children[i].style.transform = 'scale(3)';  
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  
  float: left;
  
  margin-right: 20px;

  position: relative;
}

.body.smaller {
  width: 200px;
}

.container {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  position: absolute;
  
  overflow: auto;
  
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.child {
  display: block;
  
  width: 300px;
  height: 1000px;
  
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  border: 2px solid green;

  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="body smaller">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="scale()">Scale</button>
```

As you can see, if you press the "Scale" button, the smaller one is scaled correctly and you can scroll the div as expected, the bigger one instead, shows a space as starts the scaling with a prefixed and computed margin, this issue is noticeable also with similar techniques like "justify", "box", centered text with "display: inline-block" or similar.

Comment: `left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;` is the way to do here. You have no luck with your translate

Comment: I can't use any margin as the question, so is not possibile without margins?

Comment: the question is why you cannot use margin:auto?

Comment: You can try yourself, try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Emulator000/79c5L6o8/12/

Comment: what should I notice in that fiddle?

Comment: Just using the `margin: 0 auto;` technique and if you press the "Scale" button, you could notice the issue.

Comment: what is *the issue*? I can only see a normal behavior.

Comment: The __issue__ is that the second one is scaled correctly, without any space, due to the already smaller container, the first one instead, is scaled with the original margin and this is not the expected result, I mean, it's correct for the margin way to do this and that's why I'm trying to do this with `translateX`

Comment: all these details need to belong to your question. Saying *without margin* is not accurate. You need to show the example where margin is not working fine for you because we may get it working correctly with margin.

Comment: @TemaniAfif you are right, I can surely edit the question but I need to rewrote it from scratch, also, the margin sample is not provided as we can not get it to work with it, I tried literally everything and with margins, justify, boxes and similar way you always get space when you scale the content with `transform`, the way to achieve this is only with the `translateX` or similar approaches I suppose unfortunately...

Comment: * the margin sample is not provided as we can not get it to work with it,* --> you never know ;) someone might find a trick with margin and something else so you should not restrict things. Simply detail what you want to achieve and we will logically notice what can work and what not without telling us because we will also test things.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I just provided the sample and updated the question, hope that this could help!

Comment: @TemaniAfif look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739301/css-transform-scale-down-doesnt-center-element-using-margin-0-auto-when-scale

Answer (score -1):

**Try this one:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  
  float: left;
  
  margin-right: 20px;

  position: relative;
}

.body.smaller {
  width: 200px;
}

.container {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  position: absolute;
  
  overflow: auto;
  
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.child {
//width: 300px;

  width: 80%;
  height: 1000px;
  
  position: absolute;
  
//left: 50%;  
  left: 10%;
  
//transform: translateX(-50%);   
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="body smaller">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, is not correct unfortunately, the child should stay `300px` for the correct sample issue

Answer (score -1):

The scroll bar can't display the right margin so you can remove it after the scale

```
    <head>
    </head>
    <style>
     * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .body {
      width: 400px;
      height: 100px;
      
      float: left;
      
      margin-right: 20px;

      position: relative;
    }

    .body.smaller {
      width: 200px;
    }

    .container {
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      
      position: absolute;
      
      overflow: auto;

      
      border: 2px solid blue;
    }

    .child {
      display: block;
      
      width: 300px;
      height: 1000px;
      
      margin: 0 auto;
      
      border: 2px solid green;

      transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
    </style>

    <body>
    <div class="body">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="child">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Optio sequi quos amet, doloremque earum assumenda sapiente recusandae explicabo fuga, sed provident! Aspernatur ex neque maiores voluptatibus reprehenderit! At, quasi laboriosam.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="body smaller">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius iusto numquam, autem eligendi voluptas ab qui id soluta voluptatum molestias sapiente dignissimos enim illo, impedit omnis tempore, corporis, ipsam accusantium.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button onclick="scale()">Scale</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        function scale() {
        let children = document.getElementsByClassName('child');
      for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        children[i].style.transform = 'scale(3)';
        // Remove the margin 
        children[i].style.margin = '0';  
      }
    }
    </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: The child div should have this size as the sample, couldn't be `100%` unfortunately, for the second solution, unfortunately is not working, please provide a full sample, also, if you see the updated question, if I use the `justify-content` way to center the child div, if you scale the container, the scrollbar will show a space too...

Comment: Look here for the flex sample: https://jsfiddle.net/Emulator000/wvLe8run/1/ is the same as the `translateX` one...

Comment: Use the second snippet and add remove the margin with javascript children[i].style.margin = '0';

Comment: then if you resize the browser, you get the wrong margin :) Think that  `.body` at 400px is just a sample to fit views here, normally is `100%`, anyway I think that the only way to achieve this is with some JavaScript.